# changing default document in iis 7 to MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am trying to change the default document of my localhost in iis 7. Currently it shows the default iis 7 page, I want it to show the homepage of application deployed under default website "Application".  The application is an MVC 5 web application.

I have tried adding Application into default document option and tried in web config file of the server but its still showing iis 7 page.

Answer (score 0):

MCV or Razor Web pages do not follow the default document scheme.   For example if you are setting index.php to be the default document but then you have default.cshtml beneath it, default.cshtml will still load first.   The only alternative is either to use URL rewriting to redirect your application or actually changing the routing code in your app to set default routes.